# What is an Atypon adapter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Our new project requires us to incorporate an Atypon adapter (ISAPI Filter) to be installed in the IIS. The following information was provided to us as a part of the solution specification.

•   The Atypon adapter is an ISAPI filter that will be installed in IIS and configured to intercept requests based on wildcard and regular-expression evaluation of the URL.

o   Atypon will not defer to the server, it will allow anonymous access to the web pages.

Since iam ignorant about this atypon adapter, it would be of great help if someone can actually help me on the following questions.

1) What is this Atypon filter ? (Or in more general terms, an ISAPI Filter)

2) How can we install this filter in IIS ? Will it be available as an Installation package?

3) How to configure this ISAPI filter?

4) Since we are planning to use it with an ASP.NET web application, what role is it expected to play during page requests ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISAPI filters are one of the ways for developers to inject code into the IIS pipeline. You can read a good [overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) about them. ISAPI filters are processed by IIS as request come in to the server, and have the opportunity to intercept and handle those requests.

Filters are like "global handlers" in that they are given the chance to process every request. (This differs from a normal handler, which is explicitly mapped to specific path-matching wild cards.) Filters can pretty much do anything they want, including nothing. If no filter intervenes, then IIS will handle the request it the default manner: open the file, read its contents, and write it out as-is to the client.

Typical uses for a filter might be to compress all response data, or to do custom authentication or logging before or after a request is processed, or to rewrite URLs before IIS actually gets them.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Atypon appears to be a commercial product that just happens to be implemented as an ISAPI filter.
2. That depends on the company but typically there will be an installer that hooks up ISAPI up to IIS for you. Adding a filter manually is not that difficult, you just need to add it to the ISAPI Filters list in IIS manager.
3. The configuration depends entirely on the filter; IIS has no built-in filter configuration. It could involve editing config files, or running a configuration tool to do it for you.
4. The filters will run on all requests, including ASP.NET requests. Depending on what the filter actually does, it may or may not have any effect on your web application. For example, if the filter rewrites your URLs so they no longer include a proper ASP.NET file extension, that might be bad; if they ignore everything that is not an image file request, your application won't even notice.

Answer (score 0):

An ISAPI filter sees every request made to the server before ISS see it. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

Regarding 2 and 3, it depends on the implementation. Some pointer [here (Programmatically)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525344.aspx).